# #Deleted for values of a linked Oracle table in MS Access

Tags: oracle, ms-access

I've created a simple table in Oracle 12c like so:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
TEXT VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR),
CONSTRAINT ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Then I linked it in MS Access using ODBC driver. The problem is that when I input value into TEXT and click away both ID and TEXT show #Deleted. My value gets recorded in the database but I have to requery in MS Access in order to see it.

I also noticed that if I change the datatype of TEXT field to NUMBER, it works fine. After saving the record in MS Access both auto generated ID and value in TEXT field are there. I don't have to requery anything.

This happens only when inserting. Updating works just fine.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

So, it would appear you already found the solution, but this is more of an explanation as to why it works that way. Simply speaking, if the base-table uses non-integer values as primary keys, Access rounds these integers to the nearest whole number and then (since it was not a numeric value) Access can no longer find the applicable records. So, changing the data type from `TEXT` to `INTEGER` in the table structure would give you your desired result.

Alternatively, if you're using a query to run through these, if you cannot change the keys in the Oracle table then altering the Access query type to a snapshot (in the query properties) will also bypass this problem. But from the sounds of it, this is not how you are utilizing the data.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But the primary key is always of type NUMBER in my case. On the other hand, field named TEXT is not a part of PK; however, changing its type to NUMBER somehow affects the behavior and makes everything start working Ok. But TEXT is what we have to keep Varchar2.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the Oracle ODBC driver (using the rather old version 11.02.00.01 that otherwise works ok and Microsoft Access 2016 32Bit) seems to use the unique indices and not the primary key constraint for determining the primary key.

I had a field with `NUMBER(11)` as PK with an unique index, then added a `VARCHAR2` field with another unique index. The name of the index of the `VARCHAR2` field was alphabetically before that of the `NUMBER` field.

Now, the linked table in Microsoft Access showed the `VARCHAR2` field as primary key and I had the problem with '#Deleted' appearing after entering & saving a record as you describe.

After renaming the unique index on the `NUMBER` field in Oracle to be alphabetically before that of the `VARCHAR2` field and re-linking the table in Microsoft Acces, the `NUMBER` field was the primary key again in Microsoft Access and the '#Deleted' problem was solved.